# How to reach server with SOAP request?

Tags: java, soap, request, soapui

I'm having a problem with a SOAP request on SOAP ui and my eclipse project. Triying to raise a soap request is in java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out status. However, I have connection to the server, I can reach it browsing the url and doing the request with a chrome pluging.

Anyone have any idea about what is happening?

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://schemas.meta4.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>   
     <soapenv:Body>
          <sch:login>
             <sch:in0>xx</sch:in0>
             <sch:in1>XX</sch:in1>
             <sch:in2>3</sch:in2>
          </sch:login>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

URL : http://172.22.245.34/services/Login
```

This is the expected result :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loginResponse xmlns="http://schemas.meta4.com/">
         <loginReturn>
            <sessionID>F77DD0A8FE9559B9BD633831B876D681</sessionID>
         </loginReturn>
      </loginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please, add more details to your question: Your server's code, the exact request that you are making with URL and payload and the expected result.

Comment: Please share WSDL url too. Follow sample link https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html

Comment: It is on the post : URL : http://172.22.245.34/services/Login but this is private, it is working from one point, but not from other